# Integration of KCFinder and CKEditor using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor, kcfinder

I have installed and integrated kcfinder in ckeditor but the moment I am clicking the '*Browse Server*' button in the ckeditor it is displaying "***Cannot find any of the supported PHP image extensions!***". I have checked that '**GD**' is installed using *phpinfo()*. What else I should look for?